# How can I use XGBoost in SciKit-Learn on an Air-gapped Computer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'd like to use XGBoost in SciKit-Learn, however, I'm on an Air-Gapped computer and can't install it normally using pip.

How can I install XGBoost on an air-gapped computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on an air-gapped computer there are a few things to consider.

1. What version of Python are you using?
2. What Python packages do you have available to you?
3. What are your Python package versions?

For example, [`XGBoost`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) has dependencies, if you don't have any of those dependencies you'll have to repeat the process I detail below for all those packages too. If you follow the process below, and you're missing a package, the pip installer will let you know!

As far as I'm aware, the only packages `XGBoost` relies on are:

- [`Numpy`](https://numpy.org/)
- [`Scipy`](https://scipy.org/)

## Assuming you have all dependencies

Assuming you're air-gapped computer has all of `XGBoost`'s dependencies, this is what you need to do.

Figure out which of `XGBoost`s dependencies is the most out of date. To do this you can check the package's version using the `pip list` on the command line. This will give you output that looks like the following:

[image: pip list output.]

Go onto [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) and search the package's name. On the package's page look for its release history (in the left-hand side bar) and see what date your version was published. E.g. for `numpy` I can see the most recent release was published on 26/12/2022.

[image: Numpy release history on PyPi]

Once you know which of your packages is the oldest, go to the [PyPi page for `XGBoost`](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/), look at its release history, and click on the release that falls closest to your oldest package. Say your oldest package is a version released around January 2022, in the picture below you'd click on `XGBoost 1.5.2`.

[image: XGBoost release history.]

You do this in case later versions of `XGBoost` rely on improvements to its dependent packages that don't exist in your current versions.

Once you've selected the right release you can go to its download section.

[image: Download options for XGBoost 1.5.2]

You're presented with the option to download from source or download a built distribution. The built distributions are `.whl` (wheel) files, which are Python's way of simplifying package distribution. If you want to know more about wheels, Real Python have a [great overview](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/). You don't need to understand the naming scheme, but it does help you select the right distribution.

However, if you don't want to go too deep into wheels, download the `amd64` distribution if your air-gapped PC is a windows PC, if you have an air-gapped Linux PC find out your computer's architecture (`x86_64` vs `aarch64`) and download the corresponding `manylinux` distribution, and if you have an air-gapped MAC download the `macosx` distribution (newer versions have two options, one for MAC's `arm64` chipset, and another for its `x86_64` chipset).

Finally, put your `.whl` file onto a memory stick and transfer it to your air-gapped computer. Load up a terminal, locate your file, and type out the following command:

```
> pip install your-wheel-distribution-here
```

This should install the package and you're ready to use `XGBoost`!

## Troubleshooting

If the last part of the process fails try asking questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). If you still run into issues you might have to install `XGBoost` from its source distribution. This process is exactly the same, transfer the source file to the air-gapped machine and use the `pip install your-source-distribution-here`. This will take longer as pip has to build the wheel file itself, but should still work.

If even that fails, then you're left with building `XGBoost` from source yourself, which is discussed in the [`XGBoost` documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html) (good luck!).